# Why Airflow db upgrade to v.10.3 from v1.8.2 fails?

Tags: airflow

I have airflow v1.8.2 and tried to upgrade to v1.10.3

After the update I run the command

```
airflow upgradedb
```

and get the error:

```
...
  File "/opt/nio/lib/airflow/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 536, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column 
dag.description does not exist
LINE 1: ...fileloc AS dag_fileloc, dag.owners AS dag_owners, 
dag.descri...
                                                         ^
[SQL: 'SELECT dag.dag_id AS dag_dag_id, dag.is_paused AS dag_is_paused, 
dag.is_subdag AS dag_is_subdag, dag.is_active AS dag_is_active, 
dag.last_scheduler_run AS dag_last_scheduler_run, dag.last_pickled AS 
dag_last_pickled, dag.last_expired AS dag_last_expired, 
dag.scheduler_lock AS dag_scheduler_lock, dag.pickle_id AS 
dag_pickle_id, 
dag.fileloc AS dag_fileloc, dag.owners AS dag_owners, dag.description 
AS dag_description, dag.default_view AS dag_default_view, 
dag.schedule_interval AS dag_schedule_interval \nFROM dag \nWHERE 
dag.dag_id = %(dag_id_1)s \n LIMIT %(param_1)s'] [parameters: 
{'dag_id_1': u'custom_feeds_unit_dna', 'param_1': 1}] (Background on 
this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Why db upgrade fails ? 
Should I first update to airflow v1.9.0 and not to v1.10.3 ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [link in the error message](http://sqlalche.me/e/f405), it seems to be a ProgrammingError. This implies that the syntax is off, which could be dealt with by first updating to v1.9.x because the `updatedb` code is most likely written to update it from the previous version. So the `updatedb` for v1.10.x is likely to be able to update the schema from v1.9.x and v1.9.x is likely to be able to update from v1.8.x.

However this takes a lot of time because it has to traverse every path on the system and then index it appropriately, which requires a lot of work (and a lot of resources).

If you don't need the meta data for the precious runs, you could use `airflow resetdb` to just reset the database and update the schema for the latest version.